# Writing a custom Spring @Cacheable annotation in Spring 3

Tags: spring-3, spring-cache

I'm currently writing a custom **@Cacheable** annotation that will take additonal meta-data attributes in addition to those that Spring's **@Cacheable** provides. However, Spring would need to know how to parse this new annotation. My understanding is that I'd need to implement my **own annotation parser** by extending **CacheAnnotationParser** and inject it to **AnnotationCacheOperationSource**.

But by default **AnnotationCacheOperationSource**  is using **springcacheannotationparser**, even i try to inject my custom parser as constructor injection to **AnnotationCacheOperationSource**  , which doesn't work.

Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: Meta annotation support works out of the box in Spring 4.3 so I would upgrade instead that reinventing the wheel on an old version.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll Thanks for your reply on this. Currently our project is developed on Spring 3, and we don't have enough timeline for Spring upgrade. Can you please suggest any other option with Spring 3?

Comment: @StephaneNicoll , I do see you have fixed this using CacheResolver (
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10778) in Spring 4, It would be great if you can guide us to enable this in Spring 3.

Comment: Spring 3 is EOL now so I highly recommend you to take the time and upgrade.